# How to grab X number of characters after the first Y from a string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

can someone show me how to extract characters from the middle of a string in SQL?

So for example, I only want to grab the 12 characters after the first 42 in a field.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The answer may depend on the product used.)

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first

Comment: Hint:  `SUBSTR()`.

Comment: This was actually a well asked question and I think it deserves a direct answer.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz You are right, but there are room for improvement. So giving him some tips regarding how create better question is ok.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

```
substring(mycol,43,12)
```

---

....................